# Threads in java - how to send information from one thread that the next one should start

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got a problem. When my program starts one thread starts, then inside this thread I'm waiting for something to happen(actually it's a server thread and it waits till someone connects to it and then the other thread should start) and then the other thread should start. In other words, from one thread I have to send somehow the message that the other thread should start(the first one is still running of course). I'm very new to multithread programming so I would be really grateful for your help!

Comment: Why two threads if you are waiting for a connection to arrive? Listening on a server socket for a connection to arrive is blocking (unless you purposefully use asynchronous I/O)

Comment: The usual method is that the server thread starts the thread for talking to the client.  That is, it literally calls `Thread.start()` or something similar, like adding a task to a thread pool.

Comment: fge -> it's like that: I have one thread and if the connection arrives to this thread then the next thread starts and listen if someone wants connect with it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is to pass a message via a queue.  I suggest you use an ExecutorService which wraps up a queue and thread pool.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.new.....
es.submit(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // a task you want to pass to another thread
    }
});
```

if you need to wait for a response from this thread you can submit a Callable.

```
Future<Type> future = es.submit(new Callable<Type>() {
    public Type call() {
        // do something and return a Type object.
    }
});
// do something while waiting otherwise there is no point using another thread.
Type type = future.get();
```

Comment: `call()` throws an exception ;) (which is why I prefer a `Callable` to a `Runnable`)

Comment: @fge it can throw an Exception which explains this puzzler http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/lambdas-and-side-effects.html

Comment: Yeah, I don't quite get why exceptions in lambdas have to be dealt within lambdas and are not propagated :(

Comment: @fge I think it is because functional programming doesn't have exceptions so there is no established way of dealing with these.  Ultimately, the design in Java owes much to hoe C# deals with these issues and C# doesn't have checked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CountDownLatch or Cyclic Barrier to achieve this functionality (These API's are implemented in Java 1.5)

```
**Main Class**:
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);

Waiter      waiter      = new Waiter(latch);
Decrementer decrementer = new Decrementer(latch);
new Thread(waiter)     .start();
new Thread(decrementer).start();
Thread.sleep(4000);



    public class Waiter implements Runnable{
       CountDownLatch latch = null;
       public Waiter(CountDownLatch latch) {
           this.latch = latch;
       }

       public void run() {
           try {
               latch.await();
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Waiter Released");
      }
    }


    public class Decrementer implements Runnable {

    CountDownLatch latch = null;

    public Decrementer(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.latch.countDown();

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.latch.countDown();

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.latch.countDown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
```

Another traditional way you can achieve this by using some common flag and synchronization (wait/notify) mechanism. When particular condition is occurred we will reset the flag and will notify other waiting thread. 
But above example of CountDownLatch provides a very simple way to achieve this.